# How to access attribute value in polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

HTML

```
<my-element username="{{params.username}}"></my-element>
```

Element

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
  </template>
  <script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-elemnt',

      ready: function(){
        // get attribute value
      });
  })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I can access the attribute from the template but don't know how to it access from javascript.

Comment: You have a typo tho: <dom-module id="my-element">, is: 'my-elemnt',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside the element it would be `this.username` but you might need to add that to properties for it to work

```
 Polymer({
   is: 'my-element',
   properties: {
     username: {
       type: Object,
       observer: '_updateUsername'
     }
   },
   _updateUsername: function () {
     // use this.username
   }
 });
```

Comment: I get undefined, note the username attribute is an object and not a string. If I convert it to a string it works but not as an object.

Comment: change the type to Object

Comment: i think it needs to be a string to pass in from a attribute like that (might be totally wrong) so i guess you could JSON.stringify and convery back later or pass it to the element directly with javascript document.querySelector('my-element').username = Object;

Comment: Jimi is right. Essentially, you simply need to expose/publish the `username` property by defining it under the `properties` object in your Polymer constructor. By the time `ready()` is called, Polymer guarantees that default properties are set - in your case, it's the `username` object that you passed in.

Comment: Jimi you where right with original answer. However I'm still not able to get it to do what I want. Which is to pass in the params property. I get the expected result in the template but the property is undefined in ready method.

Comment: maybe the value just isn't ready @ that time. you could do a observer in the properties object and work with the value on update in place of ready?

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html"/>
<dom-module id="my-element" username>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <p>{{username.name}}</p>
    </template>

</dom-module>
<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-elemnt',
            properties: {
                username: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true
                }

            },
            ready: function () {
                console.log(this.username);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

If you haven't declared the property it will log - undefined
For more information about the new declaration way check - 
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html

Comment: Erm. This answer is definitely wrong. First, adding the `username` attribute inside the `<dom-module>` tag is incorrect syntax. Also, setting `notify: true` for the `username` property is used to propagate changes **upwards** - it has nothing to do with accessing a property within its own scope.